# Every time I step over in debug mode Java Scanner read till next delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am reading input from Standard input. My input data has multiple lines, the first line has the total number of records, and from the second line, records begin. Every line is a record. We will have n+1 lines. So I want to read the number of first line with `nextInt()`. Here's my code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//read number of lines for scanner to break loop
int numRecords = 0;
if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
    numRecords = scanner.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

But, in debug mode, each time I press F6, I see `scanner.next()` change. When I have the following lines of testing data as input:

```
3
1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010
2,1,elmer@fudd.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,10987654321
3,2,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010
```

When I reach line 3 of my code,

```
int numRecords = 0;
```

`scanner.next()` is `3`. But, when it reaches line 4,

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
```

it's `1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123`, so the `if` condition will never be `true` because `scanner.next()` is not `3`. The next time I press F6, it changes to `Sesame`.

This is not the expected behaviour. Why?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If I understand correctly, you're surprised that when you evaluate scanner.next() in your debugger, the scanner moved to the next token. That's normal and expected: that's what scanner.next() is supposed to do. Evaluating an expression which has a side effect while debugging is not a good idea.

Comment: So, I cannot debug when using `Scanner`, if I put anything like `scanner.hasNextInt()` as condition? But I am not calling `scanner.nextInt()`, I am just evaluating. I changed `if` to `while` and no avail. Isn't this how we should code when using `Scanner`, first `hasNextXXX()` and then do `nextXXX()`?

Comment: Evaluating an scanner.next() consists in calling it and displaying the result. Store the result of scanner.next() in a variable, and evaluate that variable as many times you want. That won't have side effects.

Comment: So the Eclipse debugger is buggy...? Got it. I am warned by this new point that I have never seen.

Comment: It's not buggy at all. It's just that you don't understand what it's doing. It can't evaluate an expression without executing its byte-code. And if the byte-code changes some state when executed, then the state is changed after the evaluation. That's perfectly normal. And all debuggers will do that.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have learned something. Pity that I cannot accept your comments as answer.

Comment: Glad you learnt something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner#next` is a method with [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). Which means that its execution changes something in the environment. However the debugger doesn't distinguish [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) methods and ones with side-effects. So as soon as you've added to watches list the expression `scanner.next()` debugger evaluates it on every debugging step, advancing through the input, and that's what you observe.

There is no way to debug your current code while watching `scanner.next()`, so you should:

- change the way you are debugging the code  - remove `scanner.next()` from watched expressions.
- change the code to make it possible to debug it - add a variable where intermediate parsed input will be stored.

Considering the format of your input you can create a function to [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) the input, and then debug how each token is processed by some other function. Ideally you would like to debug a function `parseRecord(String)`, which can be easily verified without re-inputting the data each time:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
      parseRecord("1,1,bugs@bunny.com,123 Sesame St.,New York,NY,10011,12345689010");
 }
```

Comment: You really taught me something. Thanks.